# Python: how to extract only values from dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I created a dictionary `d`, where `A` is a list containing data of a `class`

```
class Driver(object):
    def __init__(self, name, raw_value, Id1):
        self.name = name
        self.raw = raw_value
        self.Indicator1 = Id1

d = {}
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if not A[i].name in d:
        d[A[i].name] = [A[i].Indicator1]
    else:
        d[A[i].name] += [A[i].Indicator1]
```

so

```
d[driver[0]] =

[0          0.002862
 1        -15.005252
 2          0.009653
 3        -15.192950
 4         14.941727
 5         44.977511
Name: 3, dtype: float64, 
 0          0.005229
 1         -0.230766
 2         14.803119
 3         -0.005263
 Name: 3, dtype: float64, 
 0         -3.756292
 1         14.827995
 2         45.595015
 3         44.964029
 4         14.820670
 Name: 3, dtype: float64]
```

as shown also in the picture from the my `notebook`

[image]

and I want get only the values from that, so:

```
v = [0.002862, -15.005252, 0.009653,-15.192950, 14.941727, ..., 44.964029, 4.820670]
```

Comment: That's not a dict and also not valid python code, how do you have this value stored? is it a string? something else?

Comment: First of all, the stuff you wrote, is not actual Python code.

Comment: I changed a bit the text and I do not understand why it is not a Python code

Comment: I retracted my answer, can't deal with down votes without explaining why it's worth a down vote. Anyway, `d[driver[0]] = [0      0.002  1    -15.00   2 ..]` is not Python code. There's no separators, `Name: 3,` is not allowed in a list...

Comment: The way you get the values however, is `for value in d[driver[0]].values()`.

Comment: is it a list of pandas Series objects?

Comment: I added a picture of the code from my notebook and what I get

Comment: You should include enough code so we can reproduce what you have. Nobody wants to play *guess the data structure*. Include whatever A is and how you get A

Comment: do `type(d[driver[0]])` because I suspect that's a huge string.

Comment: `type(d[driver[0]])` is a `list`

Comment: @emax It would be **in the best interest of everybody here** if you could tag your question with `pandas` if that's the data type you're working with. I was going bananas here trying to figure out what the hell this was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat(d[users[0]]).values
```

this will concatenate your list of pandas Series (or numpy arrays) into a single one and then you can apply `values` accessor in order to get a numpy array or a `.tolist()` function in order to get a regular Python list

Comment: Oh for fu** sake, is this a pandas data structure I've been looking at the past 10 minutes? -. -

Comment: @Torxed, yeah, `Name: 3, dtype: float64,` - that was the only way to recognize it ;)

Comment: Max, you are a wizard ^^ You deserve my upvote just for the sheer pleasure of making it so I don't rip my hair out for not understanding how the hell that output could be Python code at all.